# Rails 3 - recognize attribute from textarea and grab it, if available

Tags: javascript, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, textarea, quotes

I really want to build this from scratch and this is no request for a full code working solution, but I simply don't know where to start and what it is that I need to use and work on.

I have a comment model, and currently I'm working on allowing users to quote other users' comments. Each comment has an iteration_id, and users should simply write "#24", for example, in their comment-form textarea, to quote comment #24. I want my app to look for these kind of fragments "#[id]" in the comment-form textarea and if available do an action with them.

As I said, I don't expect anybody to give me all the code necessary for this function, but I'm not sure how to approach the implementation of this feature.
Would I do this, among others, with a Regex function?

And another related question, which I didn't want to create an own topic for: I want users to be able to simply click on a comment's id that is shown as "#16" link for example, and then this "#16" should appear pre-written in the comment-form, before the user begins to actually write his comment. Would I handle such a thing with Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For your first problem** :

I will use a regexp to catch is string started with # and followed by numbers. You can try your regexp on rubular : http://rubular.com/

For example, this regexp should work :

```
\s(#[1-9]+)\s
```

(It takes all part of your text with "space" + "#" + Any digit + "space"

**For your second problem**, i will just add the string #16 to your textarea using javascript

in jQuery :

```
$('textarea').val($('textarea').val()+' #16');
```